# Flask decorator

Tags: python-3.x, flask, decorator

In the Flask service, I have defined a decorator that I hope can be used to record some information, and then obtain the information recorded by all decorators by obtaining them. So how do I get all the decorations

My requirement is to record some function information through @xxx in a way similar to Swagger, such as @decorator ('auther','time','effect')
I had never understood the difference between a decorator and an annotation before, and just now I suddenly realized that decorators are more about extensions. They will hijack the calls to the decorated functions and then add the logic pointed by the decorator. The above is my understanding of decorators, and I don't know if it is correct.
Now I want to obtain all the information recorded by the decorator, is it feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, a decorator is simply a function that takes the decorated function as an argument. The interpreter will pass the decorated function to the decorator and set the return value back to the decorated function.

This is best illustrated with an example.

```py
def my_decorator(function):
    print('Decorated function:', function)
    return function

@my_decorator
def function(a):
    return a + 1
```

is equivalent to:

```py
def my_decorator(function):
    print('Decorated function:', function)
    return function

def function(a):
    return a + 1

function = my_decorator(function)
```

---

The above is the simple usage of a decorator, where arguments aren't needed. However, when you need to pass arguments to your decorator, things get a little messier. Take as an example:

```py
def print_when_decorated(data):
    def actual_decorator(function):
        print('The actual decorator is called, the data is', data)
        return function
    return actual_decorator

@print_when_decorated('hello world')
def my_function():
    return 12345
```

In this case, Python will first call your decorator (`print_when_decorated`) with the argument `'hello world'` passed to `data`. Then, inside the `print_when_decorated` function, another function is defined, which is `actual_decorator`. Then `print_when_decorated` returns it.

So, Python will decorate `my_function` with the return value of the `print_when_decorated('hello world')` call, which is `actual_decorator`. And thus, the code will output `The actual decorator is called, the data is hello world`.

---

So, in your case, you can store the necessary data in an attribute on the function object. For example:

```py
def decorator(author, time, effect):
    def actual_decorator(function):
        function.__my_decorator_data__ = (author, time, effect)
        return function
    return actual_decorator
```

This defines an attribute `__my_decorator_data__` on the function, which is simply a Python object. (The attribute name doesn't matter at all; you can name it whatever you'd like as long as it doesn't collide with an existing attribute.) Because Python objects are not like Java objects (for example), where all fields must be defined, you can set attributes on *most* objects (such as functions) whenever you want.

Then to get the data from the function, just retrieve the attribute set earlier:

```py
# Suppose `function` is decorated with `@decorator('abc', 'def', 'ghi')`
function.__my_decorator_data__  # returns ('abc', 'def', 'ghi')
```

Comment: Hello David, thank you very much for your reply. Your answer seems very useful to me, but I was actually prepared to give up last night. I am currently unable to fully understand your response, but I have tried to create a demo that seems to meet my requirements and I am currently researching it.
I'm very sorry, I'm a beginner in Python. Thank you again for your answer. Below is my demo for those interested in this topic to review. If there are any mistakes, please feel free to correct them,
My native language is not English,that may be some grammar errors in there . Please forgive me

Comment: (You're Chinese right? Me too!) I updated my answer with more details. Hopefully it can help you more!

Comment: （是的，我是中国人，有种赛博般的相视一笑）Your updated response has deepened my understanding of this decorator. Thank you

Comment: If my answer answered your question, please consider marking it as the accepted answer to help those who stumble upon this question looking for a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
def decorator(author, time, effect):
    def actual_decorator(function):
        function.__my_decorator_data__ = (author, time, effect)
        return function
    return actual_decorator
    
@decorator(author="John Doe", time="2023-10-12", effect="This is a decorated function")
def my_function():
    print("1234,This is a decorated function")
    pass
        
decorator_data = my_function.__my_decorator_data_
    
if decorator_data:
    author, time, effect = decorator_data
    print(f"Author: {author}")
    print(f"Time: {time}")
    print(f"Effect: {effect}")
else:
    print("Decorator data not found")
```